# how to average between values in two files?

Tags: python

I have a two file matrices, that look like this

File1:

```
{'key1',g,l,i,o,+: [0.0, 0.0, 0.92, 0.02, 0.01],'key2',g,l,i,o,+: [0.1, 0.2, 0.90,
0.26, 0.10].....'key100',g,l,i,o,+: [0.1, 0.1, 0.29, 0.19, 0.20]}
```

File2:

```
{'key1',g,l,i,o,+: [0.0, 0.0, 0.96, 0.06, 0.01],'key2',g,l,i,o,+: [0.0, 0.1, 0.95,
0.26, 0.11].....'key100',g,l,i,o,+: [0.2, 0.0, 0.23, 0.16, 0.21]}
```

Both files have the same 'keys'. I want to average the values between the two files, so the result file looks like this:

Desired output file:

```
{'key1',g,l,i,o,+: [0.0, 0.0, 0.94, 0.04, 0.01],'key2',g,l,i,o,+: [0.05, 0.15, 0.925,
0.26, 0.105].....'key100',g,l,i,o,+: [0.15, 0.1, 0.29, 0.175, 0.205]}
```

I have thought about the python script I could write, but since I am quite new to this, any quick ideas would be welcome:

```
import gzip
import numpy as np
inFile1 = gzip.open('/home/file1')
inFile2 = gzip.open('/home/file2')

inFile.next()
for line in inFile:
    cols = line.strip().split('\t')
    data = cols[6:]

for line in inFile2:
cols = line.strip().split('\t')
    data2 = cols[6:]

newdata = (data + data2)/2
```

Comment: I suspect you have some typos in your test data. Otherwise I don't see how e.g. `0.1` and `0.0` can average to `0.1`. There are a few others too. Also, what is this format? It looks a bit like a Python dict, but the `,g,l,i,o,+` doesn't make sense for a dict.

Comment: Sorry - as I am posting an example, I just averaged them in my head as to what the resultant file should look like. It is not a python dictionary (I think) but a matrix I have constructed myself.

Comment: It seems to me the averaging is easy. The problem is parsing the data from the file into something you can work with. Does each file really contain a single line of text in the format you show? If so, why are you doing `for line in ...`? How big are they? Can you read both into memory and then do the calculations? Or do you have to read a chunk from each, do the calculation on those chunks and then move on to the next chunk of each file?

Comment: Yes it contains a single line of text. There are 30,000 or so keys. But I think I do not have to read in chunks, and get away with reading at once.

Comment: How did you try to parse the dict format data from text file ? it will always produce 'str' type if you do it normally, have you parsed successfully?

Answer (score 0):

You could use regex to replace the strings and make it JSON compatible. Then you can easily convert it into a dict and then just use normal python to analyse the data (compare the dicts):

```
import re
import json

s = '''{'key1',g,l,i,o,+: [0.0, 0.0, 0.92, 0.02, 0.01],'key2',g,l,i,o,+: [0.1, 0.2, 0.90,
0.26, 0.10],'key100',g,l,i,o,+: [0.1, 0.1, 0.29, 0.19, 0.20]}'''

s2 = re.sub('\'(key\d+)\',g,l,i,o,\+', r'"\1"', s)
print(s2)
d = json.loads(s2)
print(d)
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem is your data format , as Wodin commented :

> what is this format? It looks a bit like a Python dict, but the
>   ,g,l,i,o,+ doesn't make sense for a dict.

I tried with your data , You can take hint , help from this code:

I tried with

File1.txt

```
{'key1',g,l,i,o,+: [0.0, 0.0, 0.92, 0.02, 0.01],'key2',g,l,i,o,+: [0.1, 0.2, 0.90,0.26, 0.10]}
{'key3',g,l,i,o,+: [0.0, 0.0, 0.98, 0.02, 0.01],'key4',g,l,i,o,+: [0.1, 0.2, 0.90,0.268, 0.10]}
```

File2.txt:

```
{'key1',g,l,i,o,+: [0.0, 0.0, 0.96, 0.06, 0.01],'key2',g,l,i,o,+: [0.0, 0.1, 0.95,0.26, 0.11]}
{'key3',g,l,i,o,+: [0.0, 0.0, 0.98, 0.02, 0.01],'key4',g,l,i,o,+: [0.1, 0.2, 0.90,0.268, 0.10]}
```

Code:

```
import re
pattern=r"('key\w+',g,l,i,o,\+):\s(\[.+?\])"
with open('File1.txt','r') as f:
    for line in f:
        average = {}
        pr=re.finditer(pattern,line)
        for find in pr:
            with open('File2','r') as ff:
                for line in ff:

                    for find1 in re.finditer(pattern,line):
                        if find.group(1)==find1.group(1):
                            average_part=list(map(lambda x: sum(x) / len(x), list(zip(eval(find.group(2)),eval(find1.group(2))))))
                            rest_part=find.group(1)
                            average[rest_part]=average_part
        print(average)
```

> output:

```
{"'key2',g,l,i,o,+": [0.05, 0.15000000000000002, 0.925, 0.26, 0.10500000000000001], "'key1',g,l,i,o,+": [0.0, 0.0, 0.94, 0.04, 0.01]}
{"'key3',g,l,i,o,+": [0.0, 0.0, 0.98, 0.02, 0.01], "'key4',g,l,i,o,+": [0.1, 0.2, 0.9, 0.268, 0.1]}
```